# How to prove that composition of functions is not a pointwise operation?

Tags: functions

Let $S$ be a set with at least two elements. Consider the binary operation of composition on $S^S$, the set of all functions from $S$ to $S$. How does one prove that composition of functions is not a "pointwise" binary operation? Let me give an example of what I mean. Addition of real functions is a pointwise binary operation, because it is gotten by "lifting" the binary operation of addition on real numbers to that of real functions. I hope my example has made it clear what a pointwise binary operation is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your notation of "pointwise" operation can be formalised as follow.

Let $F$ be set of all functions $S \to S$. Then operation $\bigcirc: F \times F \to F$ is pointwise, if there is an operation $*: S \to S$ s.t. $(f\bigcirc g)(x) = f(x) * g(x)$. Is it so?

For pointwise operations, if $f_1(x) = f_2(x)$ and $g_1(x) = g_2(x)$ then $(f_1 \bigcirc g_1)(x) = f_1(x) * g_1(x) = f_2(x) * g_2(x) = (f_2 \bigcirc g_2)(x)$.

But we can easily notice that there are two pairs of functions $f_1, g_1$ and $f_2, g_2$ and element $x$ s.t. $f_1(x) = f_2(x)$, $g_1(x) = g_2(x)$, but $f_1(g_1(x)) \neq f_2(g_2(x))$: let $x$ and $y$ be distinct, say $g_1(x) = g_2(x) = f_1(x) = f_2(x) = y$ and $f_1(y) = x$ while $f_2(y) = y$. Thus composition isn't pointwise.